# Passing an array with objects in to a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have an array with objects like this:

```
console.log(data);
```

Shows this in the console:

```
(40) […]
0: Object { id: 368802, start: "52990", start_id: "ABC", … }
1: Object { id: 329340, start: "52991", start_id: "DEF", … }
2: Object { id: 337521, start: "52992", start_id: "GHI", … }
​...
```

How can I pass it into datatables? This doesn't seem to work

```
table_direct = $('#table_direct').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bflrtip',
    ajax: data,
    columns: [
        { "data": "start" },
        { "data": "start_id" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Use `data`, not `ajax`, as you're providing an array of content.

Comment: Yes that was it thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to do used data (https://datatables.net/manual/data/) instead ajax ?

```
table_direct = $('#table_direct').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bflrtip',
    data: data,
    columns: [
        { "data": "start" },
        { "data": "start_id" }
    ]
});
```

As what we can read into the official documentation :

```
[
    {
        "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
        "position":   "System Architect",
        "salary":     "$3,120",
        "start_date": "2011/04/25",
        "office":     "Edinburgh",
        "extn":       "5421"
    },
    {
        "name":       "Garrett Winters",
        "position":   "Director",
        "salary":     "$5,300",
        "start_date": "2011/07/25",
        "office":     "Edinburgh",
        "extn":       "8422"
    }
]

$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: data,
    columns: [
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'position' },
        { data: 'salary' },
        { data: 'office' }
    ]
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so wrong...I like how you copied the documentation, but there's an obvious bug in the column definitions.

How it the key for each column object the "data" object.